# Linux C++ Compiling Error

Tags: c++, linux, templates, hashtable

I try to compile my c++ code in Linux using Putty. However I got various errors. I fixed some of them. I think these errors are coming because of my template functions. There may be some memory allocation mistakes too. Can anyone help?

Error:

```
[fmert@flow sevenbridges]$ gcc -o asd Source.cpp
In file included from Source.cpp:5:
dictionary.h:24:7: warning: no newline at end of file
Source.cpp:194:2: warning: no newline at end of file
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h: In static member function ‘static void std::__fill<<anonymous> >::fill(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry*, std::vector<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry, std::allocator<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry> > >, _Tp = HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry, bool <anonymous> = false]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:568:   instantiated from ‘void std::fill(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry*, std::vector<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry, std::allocator<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry> > >, _Tp = HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc:330:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, size_t, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry, _Alloc = std::allocator<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry>]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:658:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, size_t, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry, _Alloc = std::allocator<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry>]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:426:   instantiated from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(size_t, _Tp) [with _Tp = HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry, _Alloc = std::allocator<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry>]’
HashTable.h:107:   instantiated from ‘void HashTable<HashedObj>::rehash() [with HashedObj = Dictionary]’
HashTable.h:97:   instantiated from ‘void HashTable<HashedObj>::insert(const HashedObj&, int) [with HashedObj = Dictionary]’
Source.cpp:135:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:529: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry*, _Container = std::vector<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry, std::allocator<HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry> >]() = __value’
HashTable.h:26: note: candidates are: HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry& HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry::operator=(HashTable<Dictionary>::HashEntry&)
```

Dictionary.h

```
ifndef DICTIONARY_H_
#define DICTINARY_H_
#include <string>
#include <climits>


class Dictionary{
public:
    Dictionary():  code1(UINT_MAX), code2(UINT_MAX){}
    Dictionary(int c1, int c2): code1(c1), code2(c2){}
    Dictionary(const Dictionary & rhs): code1(rhs.code1), code2(rhs.code2) {}

    bool operator == (const Dictionary & rhs) const;
    bool operator != (const Dictionary & rhs) const;
    Dictionary& operator = (const Dictionary & rhs) {
        code1 = rhs.code1;
        code2 = rhs.code2;
        return *this;
    }
    unsigned code1;
    unsigned code2;

};

unsigned hashing(const Dictionary & d, int size);


#endif
```

Dictionary.cpp

```
#include "dictionary.h"



bool Dictionary::operator == (const Dictionary & rhs) const{
    return (code1==rhs.code1)&& (code2 == rhs.code2);
}

bool Dictionary::operator != (const Dictionary & rhs) const{
    return (code1!=rhs.code1)&&(code2!=rhs.code2);
}

unsigned hashing(const Dictionary & d, int size){
    return  (d.code1 + d.code2) % size;
}
```

Hashtable.h

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class HashedObj>
class HashTable{
public:
    HashTable( int size = 101 ):
      array( nextPrime( size ) ), currentSize(0){}

    HashTable( const HashTable & rhs ):
      array( rhs.array ), currentSize( rhs.currentSize ) { }

    const HashedObj & find( const HashedObj & x ) const;
    void findMax(int & maxcount, HashedObj &maxObject);

    void insert( const HashedObj & x , int amount);
    void remove( const HashedObj & x );
    void increaseCount(const HashedObj & x);
    int nextPrime(int n);
    bool isPrime(int n);


    enum EntryType { ACTIVE, EMPTY, DELETED };

private:
    struct HashEntry{
        HashedObj element;
        EntryType info;
        unsigned int count;

        HashEntry(const HashedObj & e = HashedObj(), EntryType i = EMPTY, unsigned int c = 0 )
            : element( e ), info( i ),count(c) { }
    };

    int findPos( const HashedObj & x ) const;
    vector<HashEntry> array;
    int currentSize;
    const HashedObj ITEM_NOT_FOUND;

    bool isActive( int currentPos ) const;

    void rehash( );
};




template <class HashedObj>
int HashTable<HashedObj>::findPos(const HashedObj & x) const {
    int collisionNum = 0;
    int currentPos = hashing(x, array.size());

    while (array[currentPos].info != EMPTY && array[currentPos].element != x)
        (++currentPos) %= array.size();

    return currentPos;
}



template <class HashedObj>
bool HashTable<HashedObj>::isActive(int currentPos) const {
    return array[currentPos].info == ACTIVE;
}

template <class HashedObj>
void HashTable<HashedObj>::remove(const HashedObj & x) {
    int currentPos = findPos(x);
    if (isActive(currentPos))
        array[currentPos].info = DELETED;
}

template <class HashedObj>
const HashedObj & HashTable<HashedObj>::find(const HashedObj & x) const {
    int currentPos = findPos(x);
    if (isActive(currentPos))
        return array[currentPos].element;

    return   ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
}

template <class HashedObj>
void HashTable<HashedObj>::insert(const HashedObj & x,int amount) {
    // Insert x as active
    int currentPos = findPos(x);
    if (isActive(currentPos)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            array[currentPos].count++;
        }
        return;
    }
    HashEntry b(x, ACTIVE, amount);
    array[currentPos] = b;

    // enlarge the hash table if necessary 
    if (++currentSize >= array.size() / 2)
        rehash();
}



template <class HashedObj>
void HashTable<HashedObj>::rehash() {
    vector<HashEntry> oldArray = array;

    // Create new double-sized, empty table
    array.resize(nextPrime(2 * oldArray.size()));
    for (int j = 0; j < array.size(); j++) {
        array[j].count = 0;
        array[j].info = EMPTY;
    }

    // Copy table over
    currentSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.size(); i++)
        if (oldArray[i].info == ACTIVE) {
            insert(oldArray[i].element,oldArray[i].count);
        }
}


template <class HashedObj>
void HashTable<HashedObj>::findMax(int &maxcount, HashedObj &maxObject) {

    for (int currentPos = 0; currentPos < currentSize; currentPos++) {
        if (isActive(currentPos)) {
            if (array[currentPos].count > maxcount) {
                maxObject = array[currentPos].element;
                maxcount = array[currentPos].count;
            }
        }
    }

}

template <class HashedObj>
int HashTable<HashedObj>::nextPrime(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        n++;

    for (; !isPrime(n); n += 2)
        ;

    return n;
}
template <class HashedObj>
bool HashTable<HashedObj>::isPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 2 || n == 3)
        return true;

    if (n == 1 || n % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: "using Putty" ?  you could as well say, you are trying to compile using a keyboard. how is putty relevant to the compilation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `ifndef` by `#ifndef` in `Dictionary.h`.

You also wrote `DICTINARY_H_` instead of `DICTIONARY_H_` in your `define`.

Comment: Sorry I can't edit because I don't have enough reputation, forgot to copy that part. I also changed header as well, but it has nothing to do with it.